# How to read external sensors

Tags: external, sensors, contiki, adc

I'm a beginner in Contiki World. I'm working with TmoteSky motes. I can read internal sensors but I had not found any information or examples about how to read ADC ports (pin expansions) in order to use external sensors. (Light, Temperature and Humidity).

I cannot find any information about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should look around this [link](http://senstools.gforge.inria.fr/doku.php?id=contiki%3aexamples) where you can find some examples, especially the second which discusses reading temperature periodically.

Hope it could help you.